# How can this possibly fix strict-aliasing compliance?

Tags: c++, strict-aliasing, type-punning

The following program generates compile error

`error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Werror=strict-aliasing]`

(gcc 4.7.3 with -std=c++0x -O3 -Wall -Werror)

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

struct S
{
    int t;
};


int main3()
{
    char data[100];
    std::memset(data, 0, 100);


    int offset = 15;


    // variant #1
    const S& s = *reinterpret_cast<const S*>(&data[offset]);

    // variant #2
    //const S* sPtr = reinterpret_cast<const S*>(&data[offset]);
    //const S& s = *sPtr;

    std::cout << s.t;




    return 0;
}
```

However it can be fixed by un-commenting variant #2, which simply uses an intermediate pointer variable, instead of directly dereferencing.

How come? are the 2 variants not equivalent?

Comment: Just because you don't get a warning doesn't mean that your code isn't horribly broken...

Comment: 90% of the time `reinterpret_cast` means you are doing something wrong. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Note that using `data + offset` (instead of `&data[offset]`) doesn't provoke warning.

Comment: Note that your `s` would be misaligned with an `offset` of `15`.

Comment: You are intentionally breaking strict aliasing rules. There is no point in enforcing them (imperfectly) and then working around the enforcement. Don't enforce the rules if you don't intend to follow them.

Comment: They are equivalent, but the compiler doesn't know that. It can't know if a pointer is the result of type-punning unless it catches you in the act. The "fix" only gets rid of the message, not the error. (And "it can't be a crime since nobody tried to stop me from doing it" won't hold up in court.)

Comment: It's hard for me to think the compiler doesn't see that much. (that the two are equivalent). As for "horribly broken", "intentionally breaking"... I'm interpreting a POD from data read from a socket. There is nothing horrible about that.